Is a question about whether Overwatch 2 is better on Switch or Steam (in a competitive aspect) on topic?
I want to ask a question about whether I should get Overwatch 2 on the Nintendo Switch or on Steam. I would mostly focus on what platform aiming is easier on, since aiming is a crucial part of any competitive shooter.
Is this on-topic?

We have a tag for differences between versions of a game - version-differences - so asking about certain objective differences (eg FPS, aiming, network/lag etc), especially from a competitive aspect would be ok.
However, asking which system makes it "easier" to aim with, is probably a tad too subjective - everyone is going to have a different opinion.
